# How do I modify Mule payload variables?

Tags: mule

Using Mule 3.3, I've got a Payload (which starts out as a JSON and I'm converting it to an Object using java.util.HashMap).  I can access the variables just fine from a JDBC query using:

```
#[message.payload.AddJob.variable1]
```

How do I go about adding a new variable (say variable2), or modifying the value of an existing variable?

I've tried:

```
<message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
    <add-message-property key="message.payload.AddJob.variable2" value="&quot;hello&quot;"/>
</message-properties-transformer>
```

Which had no effect.

I also tried a groovy Script (below) as suggested here: [How to add additional data to a mule payload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155062/how-to-add-additional-data-to-a-mule-payload), but it overwrites the entire payload with "hello", not just variable2.

```
payload['AddJob.variable2'] = 'hello'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what AddJob would be called.  The JSON data Mule is receiving before transforming into an Object looks like this: {"AddJob":{"Variable1":12345,"Variable2":67890}}

Comment: Cool, that should be a map of maps then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What with:

```
<expression-transformer
            expression="#[message.payload.AddJob.variable2='hello';message.payload]" />
```

?

Comment: The Expression Transformer isn't doing what I want, it's overwriting the entire payload instead of just that one variable (or map?).

This is the output from the echo component before the expression transformer:

`* Message received in service: nwa_soap_add_job_flow. Content is:              *
* '{AddJob={JobNumber=12345, Variable2=B5}}'`

After the expression transformer:
`* Message received in service: nwa_soap_add_job_flow. Content is: 'hello'      *`

What I want the result to be is:
`{AddJob={JobNumber=12345, Variable2=hello}}`

Comment: My bad, I forgot to return the map with the added element, I changed the expression accordingly.

Comment: That worked for both adding new vars and modifying existing. Thanks!

Comment: This saved me a lot of time, thanks ... I was not adding the last `message.payload` statement -_-